# Knowledge of reading and writing files by playing around with some text files. in Python 3

Tags: python

Let's say we have a text file containing current visitors at a hotel. We'll call it, guests.txt. Run the following code to create the file. The file will automatically populate with each initial guest's first name on its own line.

```
guests = open("guests.txt", "w")
initial_guests = ["Bob", "Andrea", "Manuel", "Polly", "Khalid"]
​
for i in initial_guests:
    guests.write(i + "\n")
    
guests.close()
No output is generated for the above code cell. To check the contents of the newly created guests.txt file, run the following code.

with open("guests.txt") as guests:
    for line in guests:
        print(line)
Bob

Andrea

Manuel

Polly

Khalid
```

The output shows that our guests.txt file is correctly populated with each initial guest's first name on its own line. Cool!

Now suppose we want to update our file as guests check in and out. Fill in the missing code in the following cell to add guests to the guests.txt file as they check in.

```
new_guests = ["Sam", "Danielle", "Jacob"]
​
with open("guests.txt", "w") as guests:
    for i in new_guests:
        guests.write(i + "\n")
​
guests.close()
To check whether your code correctly added the new guests to the guests.txt file, run the following cell.

with open("guests.txt") as guests:
    for line in guests:
        print(line)
Sam

Danielle

Jacob
```

The current names in the guests.txt file should be: Bob, Andrea, Manuel, Polly, Khalid, Sam, Danielle and Jacob.

Was the guests.txt file correctly appended with the new guests? If not, go back and edit your code making sure to fill in the gaps appropriately so that the new guests are correctly added to the guests.txt file. Once the new guests are successfully added, you have filled in the missing code correctly. Great!

Now let's remove the guests that have checked out already. There are several ways to do this, however, the method we will choose for this exercise is outlined as follows:

Open the file in "read" mode.
Iterate over each line in the file and put each guest's name into a Python list.
Open the file once again in "write" mode.
Add each guest's name in the Python list to the file one by one.

Ready? Fill in the missing code in the following cell to remove the guests that have checked out already.

```
checked_out=["Andrea", "Manuel", "Khalid"]
temp_list=[]

with open("guests.txt",___) as guests:
    for g in guests:
        temp_list.append(g.strip())
checked_out=["Andrea", "Manuel", "Khalid"]
temp_list=[]
​
with open("guests.txt",___) as guests:
    for g in guests:
        temp_list.append(g.strip())
​
with open("guests.txt",___) as guests:
    for name in temp_list:
        if name not in checked_out:
            guests.___(name + "\n")
```

Comment: So what's your question? Or are you expecting someone to do your homework?

Comment: This looks like you just copied and pasted a whole question from an assignment. SO is not a site for that. People can help if you have done some work and are stuck somewhere, not complete your homework.

Answer (score 0):

I complete agree with @SajanGohil but on behalf of those who have tried and can't figure this out well here you go.

Question 1:

```
guests = open("guests.txt", "w")
initial_guests = ["Bob", "Andrea", "Manuel", "Polly", "Khalid"]

for i in initial_guests:
    guests.write(i + "\n")

guests.close()
```

Question 2:

```
new_guests = ["Sam", "Danielle", "Jacob"]

with open('guests.txt','a') as guests:
    for line in new_guests:
        guests.write(line + '\n')
        print()
guests.close()
```

Question 3:

```
checked_out=["Andrea", "Manuel", "Khalid"]
temp_list=[]

with open("guests.txt",'r' ) as guests:
    for g in guests:
        temp_list.append(g.strip())

with open("guests.txt", 'w+') as guests:
    for name in temp_list:
        if name not in checked_out:
            guests.write(name + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

guests = open("guests.txt", "w")
initial_guests = ["Bob", "Andrea", "Manuel", "Polly", "Khalid"]

for i in initial_guests:
guests.write(i + "\n")

guests.close()
with open("guests.txt") as guests:
for line in guests:
print(line)
new_guests = ["Sam", "Danielle", "Jacob"]

with open("guests.txt","a") as guests:
for i in new_guests:
guests.write(i + "\n")

guests.close()
with open("guests.txt") as guests:
for line in guests:
print(line)
checked_out=["Andrea", "Manuel", "Khalid"]
temp_list=[]

with open("guests.txt", "r") as guests:
for g in guests:
temp_list.append(g.strip())

with open("guests.txt","w") as guests:
for name in temp_list:
if name not in checked_out:
guests.write(name + "\n")
with open("guests.txt") as guests:
for line in guests:
print(line)
guests_to_check = ['Bob', 'Andrea']
checked_in = []

with open("guests.txt","r") as guests:
for g in guests:
checked_in.append(g.strip())
for check in guests_to_check:
if check in checked_in:
print("{} is checked in".format(check))
else:
print("{} is not checked in".format(check))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).